# delay display inline block on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation that I am animating. However the text jumps because it shows before the animation is done, so I want to set a delay of `300ms` before triggering the `display:inline-block`. I cant get it to work? Any ideas?

```
$(".left-navigation ul li").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'width': '100%'}, 200);
    $(this).find("span.nav-text").delay(300).css("display", "inline-block");
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'width': '35px'}, 200);
    $(this).find("span.nav-text").css("display", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use callbacks!

```
 $(this).stop().animate({'width': '100%'}, 200, function(){
   // set your object visible here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`animate` has a callback parameter which will execute after the animation has completed. Try this:

```
$(".left-navigation ul li").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'width': '100%'}, 200, function() {
        $(this).find("span.nav-text").delay(300).css("display", "inline-block");
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'width': '35px'}, 200, function() {
        $(this).find("span.nav-text").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

Comment: @NickyChristensen no problem. If an answer helped you, you shoud upvote it and/or accept it by clicking the tick icon the left. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for [.setTimeout()](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/) function. Good luck!